# MongoDb C# Driver GroupBy by SubDocument

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb-.net-driver

I'am currently using last c# driver of MongoDB. What i am trying to achive is grouping documents by subdocuments.

Example Document:

```
    {
        "description" : "test",
    "dueDate" : ISODate("2020-08-08T16:02:24.000Z"),
    "dueEndDate" : ISODate("2020-08-08T18:02:24.000Z"),
    "source" : 0,
    "documents" : [],
    "attributes" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Sistem arizasi1",
            "groupName" : "ariza kaydi",
            "value" : "29e2ca21-13b0-44fb-8125-36b981b1b093",
            "groupId" : "eff0316c-3032-4123-b022-c54b465873b4",
            "type" : "definition"
        }
    ]},
   {
        "description" : "test",
    "dueDate" : ISODate("2020-08-08T16:02:24.000Z"),
    "dueEndDate" : ISODate("2020-08-08T18:02:24.000Z"),
    "source" : 0,
    "documents" : [],
    "attributes" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Sistem arizasi1",
            "groupName" : "ariza kaydi",
            "value" : "29e2ca21-13b0-44fb-8125-36b981b1b093",
            "groupId" : "eff0316c-3032-4123-b022-c54b465873b4",
            "type" : "definition"
        }
    ]},
   {
        "description" : "test",
    "dueDate" : ISODate("2020-08-08T16:02:24.000Z"),
    "dueEndDate" : ISODate("2020-08-08T18:02:24.000Z"),
    "source" : 0,
    "documents" : [],
    "attributes" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Kullanıcı Hatası",
            "groupName" : "ariza kaydi",
            "value" : "29e2ca21-13b0-44fb-8125-36b981b1b093",
            "groupId" : "eff0316c-3032-4123-b022-c54b465873b4",
            "type" : "definition"
        }
    ]}
```

Currently I have done this below,  it groups but returns AttributeId property as array.

```
        var result = _dbContext.Collection<TicketModel>().Find(filter).ToList()
             .GroupBy(q => q.Attributes.Select(c => c.Value)).Select(e => new
             {

                 AttributeId = e.Key.Select(f => f),
                 Count = e.Count()

             }).ToList();
```

What I am trying to achieve is;

```
 Name               Count
 Sistem Arizası     2
 Kullanıcı Hatası   1
```

Any help would be really appriciated.
Thanks